# How to get Jquery UI tab to be blank

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I have a JQuery UI tab dialog that is the detail of a Master-Detail interface.  When someone selects an element in the master, the tabs all get their href's populated with URLs giving details of that selected item.

For example, see 
   http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and browse to Advanced->Master Detail.

But instead of updating a second grid,  I'm updating the links of a jquery-ui tabs element like so:

```
var urls = {
        0 : "/url1",
        1 : "/url2",
};

jqgrid(....

onSelectRow: function(location_id) { 
    for (url in urls){
        $('#tabs').tabs('url', url , urls[url]+location_id );
    }
    var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs("option", "selected");
    $('#tabs').tabs('load', selectedTab);       
} 
);

$(#tabs.tabs({});
```

With html like:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a id="URL1" href="blank.html">Info</a></li>
    <li><a id="URL2" href="blank.html">History</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I shouldn't have to use a blank.html dummy link.  Is there something I can do (when I don't have anything selected in the master) that doesn't cause my tabs to cause a fetch and instead just be empty?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the tab to be blank in your coding nothing will appear in it (obviously), but if you need to empty it on page load use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divID').empty();
});
```

Comment: But if there's still a link associated with the tab, if the user clicks on it the browser will attempt to fetch that page...

Comment: Slightly confused... wouldn't you want the page to be fetched when it's clicked? Edit your main question and include your code so I can see exactly what you mean, or paste a link to your webpage or a jsfiddle page.